# Sending variables to another application and get the response from that?

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl, laravel-5

I need to send data to another webpage of different application and it will send some json data which i need to use in further instruction.

I need to send some basic information like `cus_name, cus_email, cus_phone` to that webpage and that will send some data as json format.

i got the basic idea of how can i catch the json response : like that,

```
$client = new Client();
$body = $client->get('https://securepay.google.com/gwprocess/v3/api.php')->getBody();
$data = json_decode($body);
return redirect($data->GatewayPageURL);
```

How do i send those variables to and catch the response in same controller?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Design a web service / Rest API to implement this thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send Query String Parameters in two ways.

**Include them in the URI itself.**

```
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://securepay.google.com/gwprocess/v3/api.php?cus_name=name&cus_email=email&cus_phone=phone');
```

Or

**Specify them using the `query` request option as an array**

```
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://securepay.google.com/gwprocess/v3/api.php', [
    'query' => [
                'cus_name' => 'name', 
                'cus_email' => 'email', 
                'cus_phone' => 'phone'
               ]
]);
```

**Or for Post Requests:**

```
   $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://securepay.google.com/gwprocess/v3/api.php', [
        'form_params' => [
                        'cus_name' => 'name', 
                        'cus_email' => 'email', 
                        'cus_phone' => 'phone'
        ]
    ]);
```

**and then to get the response:**

```
 $result = json_decode($response->getBody());
```

Comment: The server can't accept the 'query' . Is there any other way i can send those parameters?

Comment: explain more about the server. If the server does not except query parameters the I'm afraid it is not an API provider and you will have to figure out how the server responds to HTTP requests and mimic those using guzzle

Comment: The server response like :

`object(stdClass)#590 (10) { ["status"]=> string(6) "FAILED" ["failedreason"]=> string(19) "Invalid Information" ["sessionkey"]=> string(0) "" ["gw"]=> object(stdClass)#588 (6) { ["visa"]=> string(0) "" ["master"]=> string(0) "" ["amex"]=> string(0) "" ["othercards"]=> string(0) "" ["internetbanking"]=> string(0) "" ["mobilebanking"]=> string(0) "" } ["redirectGatewayURL"]=> string(0) "" ["GatewayPageURL"]=> string(0) "" ["directPaymentURL"]=> string(0) "" ["storeBanner"]=> string(0) "" ["storeLogo"]=> string(0) "" ["desc"]=> array(0) { } }`

Comment: The server response does not matter, You need to first figure out how the server accepts parameter. If it does accept the at all

Comment: See when i submit the the above parameter through a form it accepts it and send me the actual response but i wanted to do it through guzzle that's why.

Comment: isit a POST or get request?

Comment: Post only and i changed your code to `$client->request('POST',`